# Undefined offset: 1 on line 55

Tags: php, oop, undefined, offset

I have the problem like the title says.
I know what this problem means but i dont know how to solve it in my specific case so i nedd your help.

I have Item.php and Cart.php. In Item.php constructor is:

```
public function __construct($id, $price, $name) {
    $this->id=$id;
    $this->price=$price;
    $this->name=$name;
}
```

and in Cart.php constructor is:

```
public function __construct($items = array()) {
    if(empty($items)){
        $this->items=array();
                    $this->quantities=array();
    } else {
        foreach($items as $key => $value){
            $this->items[]=$value;
                            $this->quantities[$value]++;
                    }
    }

}
```

and function in Cart.php also is:

```
public function addItem(Item $item, $quantity = 1) {
        for($i=0; $i<$quantity; $i++){
            $this->items[]=$item;
            $this->quantities[$item->getId()]++;
        }

}
```

And the main code is:

```
$cart = new Cart();
$book = new Item(1, 59.99, 'PHP Cookbook');
$cart->addItem($book, 10);
foreach($cart->getItems() as $item) {
echo $item->getPrice(), " ", $item->getName(), " ", $cart->getQuantity($item), "<br>";
}
```

The bold line is Line:

```
$this->quantities[$item->getId()]++;
```

in method addItem.

It seems to me like when i say: `$book = new Item(1, 59.99, 'PHP Cookbook');` the php should find `$id` 1 but he doesnt. The weirdest thing is that the result is being displayed correctly on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have never set quantities(1).

Replace your line

```
$this->quantities[$item->getId()]++;
```

by :

```
if(isset($this->quantities[$item->getId()]))
    $this->quantities($item->getId()]++;
else
    $this->quantities($item->getId()] = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. But i am still having trouble with understanding the solution you gave me.
if(isset($this->quantities[$item->getId()]))      i think that this line is always be set because we already made an item with an ID and it has passed correctly. I am confused why do i need this isset function?

Comment: This isset function only verify if the ID you are adding is already in the array. If it's not we only set a value.

Comment: In the main function you have given to us, you haven't already passed your item. So the first time you have to set a line in your array with this ID. I'm not sure if I'm clear ^^

Comment: Now i get it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Don't forget to mark you're problem as solved !